# How to check if user input is the same in dictionary c#

Tags: c#, duplicates, uwp

I'm making a game in Visual Studio 2015 UWP C# where the user enters in all the words they can think of beginning with 'Ac' within a time limit and a score variable increments with each word. I have a Dictionary Collection in my C# UWP application containing all of the 'Ac' words in the dictionary. The game works fine, the only thing is that the user can enter in the same word as many times as they want and the score will still increment. Is there any way to deal with duplicate User Input? This is my Code (excluding about 400 of the words in the array to be brief and excluding the DispatcherTimer):

```
    private void btnEnter_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Dictionary<string, int> WordsWithAc = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        WordsWithAc.Add("e", 1);
        WordsWithAc.Add("t", 2);
        WordsWithAc.Add("ed", 3);
        WordsWithAc.Add("es", 4);
        WordsWithAc.Add("he", 5);
        WordsWithAc.Add("hy", 6);
        WordsWithAc.Add("id", 7);
        WordsWithAc.Add("me", 8);
        WordsWithAc.Add("ne",9);
        WordsWithAc.Add("re",10); 

        if (GlobalClassAttention.totalRecallScore >= 150)
        {
            btnLevel2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }

        if (WordsWithAc.ContainsKey(txtUserInput.Text))
        {
            GlobalClassAttention.totalRecallScore += 10;
            txtScore.Text=GlobalClassAttention.totalRecallScore.ToString();
            imgCorrectSign.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            imgX.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            WordsWithAc.Remove(txtUserInput.Text); //Doesn't remove it from the dictionary so the user can enter in the same word more than once
        }
        else
        {
            imgX.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            imgCorrectSign.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }

    private void btnLevel2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(TotalRecallLevel2));
    }
```

[image: wordserror.png]

The image shows that the user entered in "Act" twice and the score still incremented, the user shouldn't be able to enter in duplicate words.

I've tried using an array instead but was pointed towards using Dictionary. This is a link to other things I've tried.
https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1167927/How-to-eliminate-duplicate-user-input-within-the-b

Comment: every time the event is called a new dictionary is created. that is why the remove is negated. Initialize the dictionary outside of the event handler.

Comment: Thank you Nkosi. I tried that but I get an exception every time I try to enter in more than one word. I can enter in "Act" for example and then if I try to enter in "Action" I get the following exception: "An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: An item with the same key has already been added. Key: e." Normally when that exception occurs it means I've more than one instance of 'e', declared in the ictionary but I don't hagve more than one instancve of it so something else is causing that exception.

Comment: . The exception only started happening when I declared the dictionary outside of the button. Also, I can only declare the dictionary outside of the button and the ".adds" have to be within the button or they "don't exist in the current context". Like so: "  Dictionary<string, int> WordsWithAc = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        private void btnEnter_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            WordsWithAc.Add("e", 1);

Comment: That is what is causing the error. it is trying to add already existing keys to the dictionary. create the dictionary outside. do the population of the dictionary in the construction or another method that will be called only once and don't add it back in the event handler.

Answer (score 1):

Try declaring the dictionary outside of your event function. That won't initialize it every time the button is clicked.

```
Dictionary<string, int> WordsWithAc = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    WordsWithAc.Add("e", 1);
    WordsWithAc.Add("t", 2);
    WordsWithAc.Add("ed", 3);
    WordsWithAc.Add("es", 4);
    WordsWithAc.Add("he", 5);
    WordsWithAc.Add("hy", 6);
    WordsWithAc.Add("id", 7);
    WordsWithAc.Add("me", 8);
    WordsWithAc.Add("ne",9);
    WordsWithAc.Add("re",10);
private void btnEnter_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{


    if (GlobalClassAttention.totalRecallScore >= 150)
    {
        btnLevel2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }

    if (WordsWithAc.ContainsKey(txtUserInput.Text))
    {
        GlobalClassAttention.totalRecallScore += 10;
        txtScore.Text=GlobalClassAttention.totalRecallScore.ToString();
        imgCorrectSign.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        imgX.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        WordsWithAc.Remove(txtUserInput.Text); //Doesn't remove it from the dictionary so the user can enter in the same word more than once
    }
    else
    {
        imgX.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        imgCorrectSign.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks pabsusdev. I tried that but I get an exception every time I try to enter in more than one word. I can enter in "Act" for example and then if I try to enter in "Action" I get the following exception: "An item with the same key has already been added. Key: e." Normally when that exception occurs it means I've more than one instance of 'e', declared in the Dictionary but I don't have more than one instance of it so something else is causing that exception.

Comment: The exception only started happening when I declared the dictionary outside of the button. Also, I can only declare the dictionary outside of the button and the ".adds" have to be within the button or they "don't exist in the current context". Like so: "  Dictionary<string, int> WordsWithAc = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        private void btnEnter_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            WordsWithAc.Add("e", 1);

Comment: @wishfulcoder Where did you initialize your dictionary though?

Comment: You should also place the "adds" outside the button event. That's why you are getting the exception. For instance, if you enter "Act", and click the button, that leaves your dictionary with the following : [e,ed,es,he,hy,id,me,ne,re], but as soon as you click it again it will try to repopulate the dictionary starting with the "e" key, but that key is already there! That's the specific reason why you're getting the exception.

Comment: I actually tried placing the .add's outside of the button but I got the error "WordsWithAc does not exist in the current context" which made me think it had to be within the button to be reachable code? I understand the logic behind why the .add's and the dictionary should be declared outside of the button but I'm just wondering how I can do that without errors?

Comment: I tried creating a method called 'Dictionary' and calling it within the button but there's still the same problem with duplicate user entry. `code`public void Dictionary()
        {
            Dictionary<string, int> WordsWithAc = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            WordsWithAc.Add("e", 1); WordsWithAc.Add("t", 2); 
            if (WordsWithAc.ContainsKey(txtUserInput.Text)){ ...}
            }else{..}
        }
        private void btnEnter_Click
        {
            Dictionary();
            if ()
            {...}